# Error Inserting Data into tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting errors when inserting these data into the table Course.

```
INSERT INTO Course (Course_ID,Course_Name)
VALUES ('2019','CS');
VALUES ('1033','science');
VALUES ('1055','history');
VALUES ('3001','French');
```

Here is the details for creation of the table Course:

```
CREATE TABLE 
(
  Course_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Course_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Course_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to repeat `values`, you do need to use a comma between sets of values, and the semicolon to terminate the statement is optional (but good practice).

```
INSERT INTO Course (Course_ID,Course_Name) VALUES 
  ('2019','CS')
, ('1033','science')
, ('1055','history')
, ('3001','French');
```

Reference:

- [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DBYKYI20580